# Converting a string into a 24hr datetime format

Tags: c#

I have string data that comes in the following sequence:

"4:32", "1:08"

I want to convert this to 24hr time

where "4:32" becomes 16:32

Comment: How do you know whether "4:32" corresponds to 4 AM (04:32) or 4 PM (16:32)?

Comment: I have this bad data from a timetable and it works from ascending order from start of the day. I just need to understand how to convert such thing to 16:32 then im going to add logic when to deferentiate between AM and PM

Comment: Really? How does 4 in the morning become 4 in the afternoon?

Comment: I have a timetable that I know which data are AM and which Data are PM due to its ascending order. Going to create two static method that will format the ones I need for AM and the ones for PM

Comment: Add " PM" after the string and then convert to `DateTime`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse that to a `TimeSpan`, then add 12 hours:

```
var offset = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
var time = TimeSpan.Parse("4:32").Add(offset);
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the input string to a `TimeSpan`, add 12 hours, then format the `TimeSpan` with the desired string format:

```
string input = "4:32";
string output = TimeSpan.Parse(input).Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(12)).ToString("hh\\:mm");

// output: "16:32"
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, once you know if the hour is AM/PM, you could parse the value with it's suffix and then use the **HH** custom format specifier:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse("4:32 PM");
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("HH:mm"));
```

to convert it to 24h format.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#HH_Specifier

Answer (score -1):

In the simple case your question suggests, where you know beforehand that the string is 12-hour in the format `h:mm` and it refers to PM, never AM, then you can split the string, parse the hour, add 12, and reassemble it.

```
var inputString = "4:32";
var splits = inputString.Split(':');
var hourString = splits[0];
var minuteString = splits[1];
var hour = int.Parse(hourString);
hour = hour + 12;
var outputString = $"{hour}:{minuteString}";
```

If you're doing anything more complicated with dates or times, you probably want to use `DateTime` or similar classes.